# Ellipsis or wrapping with PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Is there a way to limit a `DrawString` to a specified rectangle? I want the string to be truncated (preferrably with an ellipsis "...") if it doesn't fit.

From other questions on StackOverflow and trial-and-error I've been able to get PDFsharp to wrap a text, *but only if it contains whitespace*.

```
var stringToPrint = "m m m m m m m m m m m m";
var temp = gfx.MeasureString(stringToPrint, font);
var rect = new XRect(new XPoint(leftMargin + leftPush, topMargin + topPush),
               new XPoint(leftMargin + page.Width / 2, topMargin + temp.Height));

var tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);

gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Red, rect);
tf.DrawString(stringToPrint, font, XBrushes.Black, rect, topLeftStringFormat);
```

The code above works, but as I said only if the string contains whitespace. On a string like `var stringToPrint = "mmmmmmmmmmmm";` it writes the whole string and continues past the rightside edge outside the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was implementing a method for limiting the length of `stringToPrint` so that it will fit inside the rectangle. I can do that by measuring the width of the contents and then truncating one character a time until it fits.

```
private static string GetFittedStringToPrint(XGraphics gfx, XFont font, XRect rect, 
string input)
{
    var output = input;
    var stringMeasurement = gfx.MeasureString(input, font);
    if (stringMeasurement.Width > rect.Width)
    {
        var inputMinusOneChar = input;
        do
        {
            inputMinusOneChar = inputMinusOneChar.Substring(0, inputMinusOneChar.Length - 1).Trim();
            stringMeasurement = gfx.MeasureString(inputMinusOneChar + '…', font);
        } while (stringMeasurement.Width > rect.Width);
        output = inputMinusOneChar + '…';
    }
    return output;
}
```

The call to the method would then be

```
stringToPrint = GetFittedStringToPrint(gfx, font, rect, stringToPrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp is open source, so there always is a way.

The `XTextFormatter` class is provided as a sample to get you started. You can change that class to add an ellipsis or break at other characters.

PDFsharp was created as a tool for MigraDoc. Maybe MigraDoc is a better solution for you if you do not want to deal with line-breaks and page-breaks. The `XTextFormatter` class intentionally lacks a lot of features you find in MigraDoc.